# Axis2C with OpenSSL - no OPENSSL_APPLINK error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, visual-c++, openssl, axis2c

I'm using Axis2C with OpenSSL in VC++ 2008 to access an https webservice.
Whenever the actual communication is taking place I get a runtime fatal exception :

OPENSSL_UPLINK: no OPENSSL_APPLINK.

I read that there are several things you should do, such as link in the applink.c file to my application. I did that, (using extern "C"), and I also call CRYPTO_malloc_init. Both of them are ineffective.. I'm kind of lost here.

What else should I be checking? also, does anybody know why axis2c sometimes writes to the axis.log file, and sometimes not?

Thanks!

Roey.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, using OpenSSL 1.0.1e (precompiled for Win32 from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html ).

I'm not sure what the root cause was, but the problem went away when I rebuilt my application using the static libraries for VC, instead of the DLL libraries.

In other words, this library here failed for me:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib
```

But linking again this library succeeded

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\libeay32MD.lib
```

It's possibly related to incompatibilities with other libraries (see http://forums.epo.org/installation-and-maintenance/topic1373.html) as far as I could tell, my application only used the libeay32 library.

In addition, it had to do with the PEM handling. I was able to generate an RSA key, but I couldn't write it, when I linked against the DLL instead of statically.

Comment: +1 for "PEM handling". That got me to realize that I was pointing at a non-existent cert file, which made the error go away!

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to the compile flags. 
Here is the description how you can compile Axis2c + OpenSSL 64 Bit on Windows.

**Create Axis2c 64 Bit with OpenSSL**

Versions:

- Axis2c 1.6.0
- OpenSSL 1.0.0d

Prerequisites:

- Perl 5 (64 bit version)

Perl should be in the %PATH% system environment variable

**OpenSSL**

Configure and compile OpenSSL:

```
cd <openssl_root_dir> (e.g. C:\tmp\openssl-1.0.0b)
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
ms\do_win64a
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
cd out32dll
..\ms\test
```

For preventing additional changes in the Axis2c makefile, copy the files to following dir-structure:

```
<openssl_root_dir>/bin (libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll)
<openssl_root_dir>/lib  libeay32.lib, ssleay32.lib)
<openssl_root_dir>/include/openssl (all *.h, *.c files)
```

**Axis2c**

Configure Axis2C

Change the following settings in \build\win32\configure.in:

```
ENABLE_SSL = 1 OPENSSL_BIN_DIR =
<openssl_root_dir> (e.g.
C:\tmp\openssl-1.0.0b) CRUNTIME = /MD
EMBED_MANIFEST = 1
```

Change the following settings in \build\win32\makefile:

```
LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS) /LIBPATH:$(OPENSSL_BIN_DIR)\lib
LIBS = $(LIBS) libeay32.lib ssleay32.lib
```

Compile Axis2C
cd \build\win32
nmake install

All encessary files are into the folder:
\build\deploy

The 2 OpenSSL dll files (libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll) might be copied to the deploy\lib sub folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

According to [openssl faq](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG2):

> As per 0.9.8 the above limitation is eliminated for .DLLs. OpenSSL
>   .DLLs compiled with some specific run-time option [we insist on the
>   default /MD] can be deployed with application compiled with different
>   option or even different compiler. But there is a catch! Instead of
>   re-compiling OpenSSL toolkit, as you would have to with prior
>   versions, you have to compile small C snippet with compiler and/or
>   options of your choice. The snippet gets installed as
>   /include/openssl/applink.c and should be either added to
>   your application project or simply #include-d in one [and only one] of
>   your application source files. Failure to link this shim module into
>   your application manifests itself as fatal "no OPENSSL_Applink"
>   run-time error. An explicit reminder is due that in this situation
>   [mixing compiler options] it is as important to add CRYPTO_malloc_init
>   prior first call to OpenSSL.

So just include applink.c in your project & enjoy!